# UriFormatException shown in console for unity build.How to solve this?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am running the below code

```
    string URLL = Alldetails[0].Urls[0];
    Debug.Log("URL link is = " + URLL);

    WWW imgurllinks = new WWW(URLL);
```

My console Output is shown below

```
 URL link is = "http://testing.com/test/storage//productphotos/HYTh3zUYjQKuHavNSpjQ1xeUq7laeS1WwOKPOkpQ.jpeg"
UriFormatException: URI scheme must start with a letter and must consist of one of alphabet, digits, '+', '-' or '.' character.
```

But if I give that same link directly and executes code

```
WWW imgurllinks = new WWW("http://testing.com/test/storage//productphotos/HYTh3zUYjQKuHavNSpjQ1xeUq7laeS1WwOKPOkpQ.jpeg")
```

From the API I tried by changing the link to "http://testing.com/test/storage/productphotos/HYTh3zUYjQKuHavNSpjQ1xeUq7laeS1WwOKPOkpQ.jpeg" that is removing one slash after storage in the link.
The same error but if I run the link directly than saving in a string it will work.Doesnt make any sense.

Comment: use of WWW was depreciated, while it looks fine, i cant help but wonder if theres some non printing character or something in the URLL you listed.

Comment: @BugFinder I am copying and pasting from the console which I printed using Debug.Log(URLL) ...between the " ".

Comment: I know but that doesnt make all things printable :D

Comment: @BugFinder ...Just saving and printing..Does this happen often.....SO is that an issue?

Comment: having rogue characters in things does happen if you are reading them from files which perhaps users made, so maybe i contains a tab, or line feeds, or...

Comment: "\"http://testing.com/test/storage/productphotos/HYTh3zUYjQKuHavNSpjQ1xeUq7laeS1WwOKPOkpQ.jpeg\"" .......You are right in the debug of Visual studio it is shown as above string